# sql tables to xml

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, azure

I have got few tables in sql database, one of that contains names of others, but not all. I need to load names of tables (from that special one) as a list (xdocument), and using foreach and a simple query convert all of that to one xml file. database and app is on same azure account.

i have few table like that

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name]
   (
        [P_ID]  INT            NOT NULL,
        [name] NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([P_ID] ASC)
    );
```

and one with only varchar that contains

```
table_name1
table_name2
table_name4
```

i use that simple query

```
    SELECT
    P_ID "Table_name2/@id",
    nazwa "Table_name2"
FROM Table_name2
FOR XML PATH('');
```

and get result, but only for one table

something
but i want a result for few tables in one xml using "file_converting_tables_to_xml.cs" in my app

```
<spinery>   
 <spiner title="Table_name1">
  <wart id="1">black</wart>
</spiner>
 <spiner title="Table_name3">
  <wart id="1">white</wart>
</spiner>
```

or something similar

all that i found about it don't work for me,

so please help

Comment: The "sql"-tag is not enough. Please edit your question to add the actual DBMS (vendor and version). From the syntax I assume, it's SQL Server?

Comment: Add DataTable(s) to DataSet then use the DataSet WriteXml method to save to one file.

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If this was SQL Server you might try this:

--Creating two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table_name1
(
    [P_ID]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [name] NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([P_ID] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table_name2
(
    [P_ID]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [name] NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([P_ID] ASC)
);
GO
```

--Fill them with your sample data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_name1 VALUES(1,'black');
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_name2 VALUES(1,'white');
GO
```

--Use `UNION ALL` to combine the results and `FOR XML PATH` to create the proper namings

```
SELECT 'Table_name1' AS [@title]
      ,P_ID [wart/@id]
      ,name [wart]
FROM Table_name1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table_name2' AS [@title]
      ,P_ID [wart/@id]
      ,name [wart]
FROM Table_name2
FOR XML PATH('spiner'),ROOT('spinery');
```

--Clean-Up (Carefull if real data!)

```
GO
--DROP TABLE dbo.Table_name1;
--DROP TABLE dbo.Table_name2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it's still not what i looking for :)

Comment: @JaNieWiem please be more specific. What are you looking for?

Comment: @JaNieWiem, I just re-read your question... If you want help, you must invest a bit on your own. You did not even add the rigth tag for your DBMS. My answer produces **exactly** the expected output as you've written it. Without your explanation nobody knows what your are looking for.